# turn off illustrator guides and reset the canvas

Tags: adobe-illustrator

[image]

I'm not a pro in illustrator so I don't fully know the correct terminology but this morning I opened it and it looks like this. how do I turn off all those green guides and how to I reset the canvas to make it so the outside is gray and only the inside white? I've tried resetting and that didn't do anything

Answer (score 1):

You've opened a **Video and Film** document profile.

Simply close the document and open a new document using a profile *other* than the Video and Film profile. For just general drawing the Print profile works best for me, but the Basic RGB or Basic CMYK may work well for you also.

[image]